# How to install custom .appx from Local storage after packaging from Visual Studio 2013 update 4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm totally Stunned by the fact that I'm getting no Error when the custom app, I made using Visual Studio 2013 ( Update 4 ), when I Deploy my Solution with Windows phone attached to Pc via Usb. The app work flawlessly. 
But When I create a package and copy the Generated .appxbundle or .appx file to Phone Storage or SD card of Device and install it, It give me no error but on Menu or Home Menu no new app is installed.

Sometimes Back I installed Visual Studio 2017 and the package I created from there, I copied on phone storage and installed....it installed and even app was visible on new app installed but as it lacks windows phone ( webview ), so I choose 2013 instead.

How can I solve this or can I even solve it??

1) Phone: Nokia Lumia 540 ( windows 10 installed )
2) Visual studio  ( Update 4 )
3) Windows 10 installed on Pc with 4 GB Ram.

Any help would be Greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe you miss the dependencies . so also apply those appx files

Comment: open your visual studio select debug mode then create app package but not for store and in debug mode then the app package .appx will be larger in size because it inc. all things app need to run or install then copy it to your storage and open file explorer and simply install it and wait 30 sec on file explorer then come to home screen app will be appear . Note* your app sdk should not higher than mobile installed windows 10 version. if it is work reply i will provide this solution in detailed

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Thanks for solution but It doesn't work, when I deploy solution instead  of build,  it works and I can see the new app installed in home screen. But even if I build package in debug mode ..and copy .appx file in explorer and install and wait for 30 sec..but no new app can be shown in home screen.

Comment: Try to create release appx package and mention if any error and first check your release mode through visual studio it is launch or not and why you dont want publish in store , you can use dev share app in the store if any problem

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Ok I'll update you soon if that wrks or not...I'm out now. I'm from Nepal and credit cards are rear here, we don't use credit cards ..so I'm not able to make a developer account..so i'd like to distribute the app to my Friends ( actually app is for my college project ) to help them for Class Routine, attendance and much more.

Comment: you should use Dev Share app it really for you 
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/dev-share/9nblggh51s0c     but if you want to distribute locally only to friends as a project you should distribute offline